# XPath get the attribute value without the attribute name

Tags: xml, xpath

There are numerous similar questions, but none of them contain an answer.

From XML `<root><child id="10"/></root>` I want to get `10`.

I use Perl xpath implementation version 5.18.

What I have so far:

```
echo '<root><child id="10"/></root>' | xpath '//root/child/@id'
```

From what I have read this should do the job:

```
echo '<root><child id="10"/></root>' | xpath 'string(//root/child/@id)'
```

But I get:

```
Query didn't return a nodeset. Value: 10
```

Comment: @Vanna it does not make any difference in this context

Comment: just try it, the output is the same `id="10"`

Comment: `echo '<root><child id="10"/></root>' | xpath 'string(//@id)'` fails with `Query didn't return a nodeset. Value: 10`

Comment: `getting the value with an error that is` is not an option, there cannot be any error. `-q` is not supported.

Comment: I had the same question. Rather than redirecting stderr to null, you can also use the `-q` switch to `xpath`. So you still get "real" errors printed out. So in your example, this should work: `... | xpath -q -e 'string(//root/child/@id)'`.

Answer (score 0):

(X-posting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695505/getting-attribute-value-from-xml-in-bash-script-with-xpath-string#comment94246909_53695583) in case other folks run into this problem - thanks Cyrus!)

**TL;DR: add `2>/dev/null` to the end of your `xpath` command**

The `Query didn't return a nodeset. Value:` part is sent to `stderr`, while the actual output (in this case `10`) goes to `stdout`.

We can hide `stderr` by piping it to `/dev/null`:

`echo '<root><child id="10"/></root>' | xpath 'string(//@id)' 2>/dev/null`

This should give you `10`.