# Getting attribute value from XML in bash script with XPath string()

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, ubuntu-18.04, xmlstarlet

Preamble:
This is not a duplicate since all other topics do not answer my specific issue.
I'm on Xubuntu 18.04
using libxml-xpath-perl 1.42 (if that matters)

Problem:
I have an XML, let's say like so:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <somechild foo="bar" />
    </level1>
</root
```

I want to get the value `bar` from `somechild`s attribute `foo`.
However, when I query

```
FOO=$(xpath -e '/root/level1/somechild/@foo' $XMLFILE)"
```

in my bash script it returns `foo="bar"` instead of `bar`.

I've already researched this issue and found out that I have to do something with string() but I just cannot figure out what the right syntax is for that.

I've tried the string() function in various places but the closest I got to success, so far was

```
FOO="$(xpath -e 'string(/root/level1/somechild/@foo)' $XMLFILE)"
```

In this case `echo $FOO` gives me

> Query didn't return a nodeset. Value: bar

Still not what I want but at least no error and the Value is recognized as `bar`

How do I use this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With valid XML:

```
xpath -e 'string(//root/level1/somechild/@foo)' file.xml 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
xmlstarlet select --text --template --copy-of 'string(//root/level1/somechild/@foo)' file.xml
```

or

```
xmlstarlet select --text --template --match '//root/level1/somechild' --value-of '@foo' file.xml
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Comment: Ok, I find that behaviour of xpath weird but sending the output 2 to /dev/null solves the problem. What is also weired that in commandline `xpath -q ...` works and there is no error message. However in my bash script `xpath -q ...` still gives me the error. Whatever...I will go for `2>/dev/null` Thanks

Comment: Note that the XPath expression is returning an attribute node, and the way in which an attribute node is presented in the output is up to the calling application. If you want the string value, then the string() function gives you it, but some applications can only handle XPath expressions that return nodes.