# Getting multiple attribute values from XML via xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I'm trying to retrieve multiple attribute values (`foo` and `bar`) with one single xpath query.

This is my XML content (test.xml):

```xml
<root>
    <level1>
        <child foo="bar" bar="foo" />
    </level1>
</root>
```

Current best solution based on:

- [Getting attribute value from XML in bash script with XPath string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695505/getting-attribute-value-from-xml-in-bash-script-with-xpath-string)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52711/xmllint-display-values-of-more-than-1-attributes-in-single-execution
- ..and a lot of googling

```sh
xmllint test.xml --xpath '//root/level1/child/@*[name()="foo" or name()="bar"]'
xpath -q -e '//root/level1/child/@*[name()="foo" or name()="bar"]' test.xml
```

..which both return:

```
 foo="bar"
 bar="foo"
```

However I would like to have an output similar this (attribute names and `="` removed):

```
bar
foo
```

Wrapping the query with `string()` sadly doesn't work.

Is it actually possible to get multiple attribute values at once, or am I trying something impossible?

I'm aware that I could pipe the output through `cut` or `awk` but that isn't possible in the actual environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

There is a function available called [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/concat) which allows exactly the functionality I was looking for:

```sh
xpath -q -e 'concat(string(//root/level1/child/@foo), "\n", string(//root/level1/child/@bar))' test.xml
```

This allows me to query both attribute values (using `string`) in one query.